# keep webpack dev-server running even after terminal closes

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hi is there a way i can keep webpack devserver running even after closing terminal.

"scripts": {

```
"dev-server": "npm run templates && webpack-dev-server -d --https --port 28443",
```

}

when i run npm run dev-server it starts but after closing terminal webpack devserver also closes is there any way to keep it running with pm2 or any other method.

Answer (score 2):

use `nohup`

So if the script command is "dev-server" (according to your snippet), then go to your project root directory (where the package.json file is, which has your "scripts" section):

1. If on unix environment, just run `nohup npm run dev-server &`
2. If on windows, install `git bash` - it's sort of a mini unix environment for windows. And then run the `nohup npm run dev-server &`

This will start the webpack dev server and keep it running on the background

For me, my script section is

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open"
}
```

and the above command that I mentioned works fine

Comment: For the reader's information, "nohup" ensures that no SIGHUP is passed through to running processes from the interactive terminal when the terminal "Hangs Up" – this is the signal that causes the dev server to exit whenever the terminal was closed, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` did somehow not work for me, but i was able to make it work with [forever](https://github.com/foreversd/forever).

```
sudo npm install -g forever
```

```
forever start -c "webpack serve" ./
```